# Add new ListObject of XML source to Excel worksheet by VSTO add-in

Tags: xml, excel, vba, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to insert data from XML to Excel sheet. I use the following method:

```
sheet.ListObjects.AddEx(SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcXml, Source: ???)
```

but I don't know what to provide as a source. I tried to enter there XML data as a string but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas?